# Can I store static html pages as zip file at OSS server and visit it by web browser?

Tags: html, zip, gzip

As I know, common technical solution which is used to store **static pages** at OSS server is just store them like below

```
Bucket
 ├── index.html
 ├── error.html
 ├── example.txt
 └── subdir/
      └── index.html
```

I also know that when transfering some large files, server could **compress the file** in some format and **web browser decompress it**. *Is this right?*

So can I directly store the compressed page on OSS server? When someone wants to visit it, just send him the zip file and rely on the web browser unzip it.

Comment: Google finds *multiple* pieces of software called *OSS server*, you'll need to be more specific. ("Does my web server support precompressed files?" isn't really a programming problem though and is probably better asked on [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: I use Aliyun OSS. https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/object-storage-service/latest/static-website-hosting-overview